# Requirement to populate Pull Request Template

Tags: github, pull-request

Is it possible to require someone fill out a pull request template before merging?

For example, I would like people to populate "ticket number" before merging into the main branch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your goal is to enforce requirements on the merge message, I don't think you can do that at the moment.

However, if your requirement is simply that someone have certain content in the pull request, you could well have a CI job that looks up the pull request and verifies it contains necessary information before merging.  You would probably want to make such a job easily re-runnable so that once the author has edited the pull request, they can kick it off again.